# Storm-crawler and Elasticsearch version

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm working on getting the latest version of ES (5x) working with [Storm-crawler](http://stormcrawler.net).

I did what was mentioned [here](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/453#issuecomment-292747073%3E), I cloned the repo, mvn clean install to build and then I entered all the mvn commands mentioned [here](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch) and it all worked.

The thing I'm confused about is when it comes to the pom.xml file, for the `version number`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do I enter 1.5 there or keep it as 1.4? I'm still trying to get get better with Maven and the Java build process and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building the project on your local post cloning the repo.

You shall try

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler -DarchetypeArtifactId=storm-crawler-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.5-SNAPSHOT
```

and then further you can then edit the pom.xml and add the dependency for the Elasticsearch module as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for concise answer. I'm new to Maven and all this Java jar stuff. Your answer helped me see things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

StormCrawler 1.5 should be released soon and as suggested by @nullpointer you need to change the version to 1.5-SNAPSHOT; the tutorial was based on SC 1.4 which uses ES 2.x

See [blog](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2017/05/avoid-common-pitfalls-when-upgrading.html) for potential issues when upgrading to ES5.

Comment: the mapping in the ES_IndexInit.sh is for ES5x, I got everything installed for 2x and had some trouble with getting the mapping types right, so I decided to go with ES5x and do as I described in my question. I actually got the old init script from the github history but decided to go with ES5x.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep it as 1.4, because this is the latest version of storm-crawler-elasticsearch plugin.